# Apply successive filters to an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, functional-programming

I have an array of some objects, perhaps strings or numbers. I want to apply some arbitrary filters to this array, and I want to be able to specify the order of the filters. Here's an example (I know that in this toy example, order doesn't matter, but I want to be able to specify for another case):

```
filters = [:filter_odd, :filter_multiple_five]
all = (1..10).to_a #[1, 2, ... 10]

filter(all, filters)
# should return [5]

# where, i.e.:
private

def filter_odd(numbers)
  numbers.select(&:odd?)
end

def filter_multiple_five(numbers)
  numbers.select { |number| number%5 == 0 }
end
```

Now, I know I can just do this:

```
odds = filter_odd(all)
filter_multiple_five(odds)
```

But I keep having to add more filters as my requirements change, and it isn't very satisfying to do it this way. I am searching for a clean, functional way of doing this in Ruby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, spoiler, I figured out one solution. Since I could not find this exact problem anywhere I decided to post it here:

```
def filter(array_of_numbers, filters)
  filters.inject(array_of_numbers) do |remaining_numbers, filter|
    send(filter, remaining_numbers)
  end
end
```

So, if you had some filtering methods:

```
private

def filter_odd(numbers)
  numbers.select(&:odd?)
end

def filter_multiple_five(numbers)
  numbers.select { |number| number%5 == 0 }
end
```

And a list of filter method names (as symbols) and some data:

```
filters = [:filter_odd, :filter_multiple_five]
all = (1..10).to_a #[1, 2, ... 10]
```

Calling `filters` returns the correct result. After the first filter, it yields just the odds to the block and after the second filter it returns odd multiples of 5:

```
filter(all, filters)
=> [5]
```

Comment: I agree that `inject` is the way to go here. You could improve your answer by giving an example.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `blocks`, it is a flexible way. If you are not familiar with blocks, this can be used as a reference: [understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas](http://www.reactive.io/tips/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/)

```
class Array
   def filter
       self.select{ |e| yield(e)} if block_given?
   end
end

arr = (1..10).to_a
puts arr.filter{ |n|  n % 5 == 0 }.inspect
puts arr.filter{ |n|  n.odd? }.inspect
puts arr.filter{ |n|  n % 3 == 0 }.inspect
```

output:

```
[5, 10]
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
[3, 6, 9]
```